# Creating a button from data from Author meta

Tags: author, user-meta

I'm creating an author box for every WordPress post, and I'm trying to pull a link from the author meta.

This code works fine, and prints the (however unclickable) URL but I want to compile this into a clickable button like "Follow on Snapchat".

Can someone give me a push in the right direction?

```
<?php
$snapchat_profile = get_the_author_meta( 'snapchat_profile' );
    if ( $snapchat_profile && $snapchat_profile != '' ) {
     echo '<a href="' . esc_url(     the_author_meta('snapchat_profile')) . '"></a>';
    }

        ?>
```

Comment: `echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $snapchat_profile ) . '">Follow on Snapchat</a>'`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just created an empty link, it has correct link but no inner text:

```
echo '<a href="' . esc_url(     the_author_meta('snapchat_profile')) . '">Follow on Snapchat</a>';
```

And since you already stored the link in `$snapchat_profile` variable, no need to call the `the_author_meta('snapchat_profile')` function once again (it will only reduce in a few bits of extra memory usage and ..) so you should end up with this:

```
$snapchat_profile = get_the_author_meta( 'snapchat_profile' );
if ( $snapchat_profile ) {
    echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $snapchat_profile ) . '">Follow on Snapchat</a>';
}
```

Comment: Perfect dude. Still learning the WP ropes ;) 

Used here: https://chrisschwartze.com/scare-the-shit-out-of-me/